# Java Prefuse graph copying a node to another graph

Tags: java, graph, prefuse

I have a 2x2 grid of graphs in JPanels. In the top left graph i have a load of nodes, when I click on a node I want that node to be copied to the next graph so it appears there.
Firstly I am making the graphs
Then I add data to the top left graph
Then I attach those graphs to panels by creating visualisation, and a display based on that visualization.
I add a ControlListener to the display to handle clicking on nodes - I pass that the graph I want the node to be copied into
Then in the itemClicked method, I am doing Node node = graph.addNode(). I get no errors, but I dont see the node either.
Any ideas why  - do I have to refresh the graph or something?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the graph by running the action list on the visualization where the node is added.